# How to track itunes podcast data with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, rss, itunes, podcast

I'm trying to track podcast data. They told me I have to use a .mp3 extension or else it won't load. So I can't just do like track.php, it would have to be track.mp3 which redirects to a php file. I was wondering if I could simply use Codeigniters url:

http://domain.org/index.php/feed/listen/music.mp3

Then in the feed class I'd have the listen function and it would send music.mp3 as a paramater. Would that work? or would it break because of index.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many network-based trackers (like RawVoice/BluBrry) work via redirect. So for instance http://trackerurl.com/accountnumber/?r=http://media.podcasturl.com/myshow.mp3

Comment: The idea is that someone clicks what appears to be a link to the audio file, but it's actually to a php file that redirects them after storing tracking data. iTunes says that link has to be a .mp3 extension.
According to http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html#tracking:

The URL before the GET-style form values (before the first ?) must end in a media file extension (e.g. mp3). To work around this, the feed provider can alter their URL from this:
http://www.podcaster.com/load.php?f=&Wipeout.php
to this:
http://www.podcaster.com/load.mp3?f=&Wipeout.mp3